# Image quality is bad when importing image into Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, interface-design

When I make a screenshot for my app on my phone, the picture looks clear but when I import it to the mockup phone in Photoshop it doesn't show up clearly.

How can I make a HD screenshot for my app to then publish it in as a Google developer?

[image]
[image]

[full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FD6pF.jpg)                      [full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzhDt.png)

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What do you mean by "it shows bad and confusion"? Please edit your question and add more details. It's very difficult to answer questions when there is nothing to look at. It would be extremely helpful if you could post an example image of what it should look like, and an example of the problem caused when you import it into Photoshop. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question with images. It's now much clearer. I have now added an answer.

Comment: It would help if you described how you placed it there and at which point it started looking stretched like that. Or if you can show us a video of that.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you have distorted the image by stretching it. The phone image is not the same aspect ratio as the screen capture. That's the source of the problem.

Stretching images degrades their quality causing distortion and resampling. It's not recommended to do that.

It's not caused by your screen capture app, or Photoshop.  You can fix it by using an image of a phone which has a screen with the same aspect ratio as your phone.

Comment: thank you very much bro but what is the step I have to follow to make screenshot professionl

Comment: @HealthyBeauty I already told you how to fix it in my answer.

Comment: how  ? because if I change the width and height is dont keep her clairty

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you have non-square pixel aspect ratio enabled?

[image]